# Owin WebApi 2 Hostname IntegratedAuth Failing - 400 error and bad credentials

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, owin, httplistener

I have an intranet application using OWIN self hosting to serve a SPA/WebAPI 2 type site. Everything works great as localhost:port, and IP:port, but hostname:port fails for IE and Chrome.  Yet the application works with FireFox.

I believe this is due to the integrated authentication.  Chrome returns ERR_INVALID_AUTH_CREDENTIALS, and IE returns 400 bad request.  Fiddler doesn't show much difference in the headers of the request/response, except that the Authentication comes through and I get a 200 in FF, a 400 in IE and a 401 in Chrome.

Most of my code was "borrowed" from SO articles or MSDN tutorials.Here's my Program.cs:

```
string baseAddress = "http://*:9000/";
using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(new StartOptions(baseAddress) { ServerFactory =  "Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener" }))
{
    // Keep server operational till stopped
    Console.WriteLine("Started, Press any key to stop.");
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine("Stopped");
 }
```

Here's my startup.cs:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    var listener = (HttpListener)appBuilder.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];
    listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication;

    // Configure Web API for self-host. 
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    appBuilder.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
    {
        RequestPath = new PathString(string.Empty),
        //  path to static files.
        FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem("./public"),
        EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false
    });
}
```

I also made sure to set the url reservation using netsh:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:9000/ user=Everyone
```

Both IE and Chrome attempt the intranet model of Integrated Authentication and attempt to send the credentials immediately in all of our intranet applications.  FF always prompts for credentials and never auto-authenticates.  This has me leaning towards authentication as the problem.

Does anyone have an idea for what I can check to validate the authentication side of things?  Fiddler didn't illuminate the request very well.  Breakpoints never seem to get touched in the app when requesting against the host.

I think there could be a group/local policy that is getting in the way of proper authentication, but I'm not certain where to start looking.

### *edit - updated tags

### *update

Some further testing indicates that forcing auth to NTLM (versus integrated) allows Chrome to auto-logon, FF to work the same as it always did, and IE in a weird place.

IE will autologon, but then fail to load the JS on the page, or Prompt for a user and then login properly depending on FQDN vs shortname.  I believe this is due to the default IE behaviors and trusted/intranet site settings.

I now have a work around, but it'd still be nice to figure out kerberos if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: I looked at the auth section of fiddler and discovered that when the connections failed, the browsers were attempting to connect via kerberos.  But successful connections occurred over NTLM.

Forcing the AuthenticationScheme to NTLM, got me closer, but still not happy.  I'm passing initiaul Auth, but then not able to get past my authorization in WebApi.  As I get more details I'll respond.

Comment: Some further testing indicates that forcing to NTLM allows Chrome to auto-logon, FF to work the same as it always did, and IE in a weird place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the code to

```
HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)app.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];
listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Ntlm;
```

In Self Host Web API, it solved the issue.

Comment: This is what I did and it works.  It drives me a little nuts not fully understanding why the integrated authentication w/ kerberos worked locally but not remotely.  But I can live with it...